# Can't access a property of a Embedded class via JPA

Tags: spring-boot

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TIPO_CONTRATO", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
public class Contrato extends AuditorEntity implements Serializable, Clonable {
   
   @Column(name = "CIF_NIF")
   @JsonView(Views.Buscador.class)
   @JsonProperty("cifNif")
   private String cifNif;

   @Column(name = "NOMBRE_SOCIEDAD_PERSONA")
   @JsonView(Views.Buscador.class)
   private String nombreSociedadPersona;
}
```

And i have this Embeddable class called `CuentaBancaria` from `Contrato` table:

```
@Embeddable
public class CuentaBancaria implements Serializable {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6835775213299596371L;

    @Column(name = "TITULAR_CUENTA")
    @JsonView(Views.Completo.class)
    private String titularCuenta;
}
```

In `ContratoRepository` i'm trying doing a JPA Query finding the "`titularCuenta`" field of Cuenta Bancaria finding by the `cifNif` field of `Contrato`. But it's not working. What can i do to solve this?

```
@Query(value="SELECT c.CuentaBancaria.titularCuenta FROM Contrato c WHERE c.cifNif= ?1 AND c.nombreSociedadPersona IS NOT NULL AND ROWNUM = 1")
    public String getNombreLegalCliente(String cifNif);
```

The error which is throwing:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property:
> CuentaBancaria of: com.xxxx.Contrato

Comment: Can you update your Contrato class with fields?

Comment: @BranislavLazic Yeah, i have updated the question

Comment: And those are all fields?

Comment: You don't have field with `CuentaBancaria` type with `@Embedded` annotation in your `Contrato` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `CuentaBancaria` field in `Contrato` class. That's why JQL complains.

Add the field in the class with `@Embedded` annotation:

```
public class Contrato extends AuditorEntity implements Serializable, Clonable {
    @Embedded
    private CuentaBancaria cuentaBancaria;
}
```

And fix the JQL expression to:

```
@Query(value="SELECT c.cuentaBancaria.titularCuenta FROM Contrato c WHERE c.cifNif= ?1 AND c.nombreSociedadPersona IS NOT NULL AND ROWNUM = 1")
    public String getNombreLegalCliente(String cifNif);
```

Comment: But it's not possible to do without adding this?

Comment: You need that field. Or, I don't know, to do some dirty hack with plain SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, since your class  [ CuentaBancaria ] is annotated with @Embeddable, it needs to be embedded in the parent class in this case [ Contrato ] with @Embedded.

Then, harnessing  **Spring Data JPA query Lookup strategies**, you can access property fields of your embedded class with ease or you could still go by the  @Query() approach
[Query lookup Strategy from Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.sample-app.finders.strategies)

Sample demo code with your problem with a minimal implementation:

```
Entity-Class
--------------

@Entity
public class Contrato{

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long contratoId;

   @Column(name = "CIF_NIF")
   private String cifNif;

   @Column(name = "NOMBRE_SOCIEDAD_PERSONA")
   private String nombreSociedadPersona;

   //we call the embeddable class in this parent class with @Embedded annotation
   @Embedded
   private CuentaBancaria cuentaBancaria
}

 Embeddable-Class
 -----------------

 @Embeddable
 public class CuentaBancaria{

  @Column(name = "TITULAR_CUENTA")
  private String titularCuenta;
}
```

Now in your **ContratoRepository** class, we could have

```
@Repository
public interface ContratoRepository extends CrudRepository<Contrato, Long> {

  Optional<Contrato> findByCuentaBancariaTitularCuenta(String cifNif);
}
```

which interprets to JPQL snippet:

```
c.cuentaBancaria.titularCuenta FROM Contrato c WHERE c.cifNif= ?1
```

**NOTE:** Notice the **query method name** matches the exact names in the classes and their corresponding fields, preceded by **findBy**